# How to properly add an Android device to Linux for device debugging?

Tags: android, linux

On a Ubuntu 13.10 Linux I am trying to add an Android device to be able to debug it. The device is a 'Vodafone Smart II' (alcatel smart 2 II) and the interesting line of `lsusb` is as follows:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 18d1:0002 Google Inc.
```

I therefore added the following line to the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` according to some similar posts found on the web and on SO:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1",MODE="0666",GROUP="plugdev"
```

Then I change file permissions, reloaded the table and tried again with no success:

```
> sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
> sudo service udev reload
> adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I also tried to reconnect the device, and to leave out the `SYSFS` part and the `GROUP` part as well. But I always get a list of question marks.

How can I properly add this device to Linux for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaunch adb daemon as root. Simply go to android-sdk/platforms-tools via shell and type:

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

It should work correctly from that moment.

Comment: Yes, the question marks vanished and numbers appeared!